# VC2013: my app crashes trying to lock a mutex

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I receive crash dumps. Some of them has the following stack trace:

```
msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::details::_RegisterConcRTEventTracing() Line 240   C++
msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::CreateWithoutInitializing(const Concurrency::SchedulerPolicy & policy) Line 283   C++
msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::CreateContextFromDefaultScheduler() Line 571  C++
msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::CurrentContext() Line 404 C++
msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::critical_section::lock() Line 1031    C++
msvcp120.dll!mtx_do_lock(_Mtx_internal_imp_t * * mtx, const xtime * target) Line 67 C++
app.exe!vmsRaisesVaEvents::SubscribeToVaEvents(vmsConsumesVaEvents * pSubscriber) Line 14   C++
app.exe!vmsSiHtml5UiApp::MakeSureSplashCreated(CSiHtml5AppStartingSplash::SplashScreenMode ssmRequired) Line 458    C++
app.exe!vmsSiHtml5UiApp::PerformWbaPreInitializationIfRequired() Line 63    C++
app.exe!vmsSiHtml5UiApp::RunAsNonUiAuxiliaryProcess() Line 140  C++
app.exe!vmsSiApp::Run() Line 106    C++
app.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, wchar_t * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 23   C++
[External Code] 
[Frames may be missing, no binary loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!0000000076ed3021()    Unknown
```

My app is just starting and initializing. It has one thread only (main thread) of my app and 5 other threads which were created by something I don't know. But they does not belong to my code.

In MakeSureSplashCreated function I create object.

```
m_spSplashMgr = std::make_shared <vmsSiHtml5AppStartingSplashMgr>
```

And subscribe to its events:

```
m_spSplashMgr->SubscribeToVaEvents (this);
```

Object is derived from vmsRaisesVaEvents class to provide this functionality. Its code:

```
class vmsRaisesVaEvents
{
public:
    vmsRaisesVaEvents () :
        m_rasingEvents (0) {}

    virtual ~vmsRaisesVaEvents () {}

    void SubscribeToVaEvents (vmsConsumesVaEvents *pSubscriber)
    {
        std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock (ms_events);
        wait_for_events_raising_complete (lock);
        assert (std::find (m_vSubscribers.begin (), m_vSubscribers.end (), pSubscriber) == m_vSubscribers.end ());
        m_vSubscribers.push_back (pSubscriber);
    }

    void UnsubscribeFromVaEvents (vmsConsumesVaEvents *pSubscriber)
    {
        std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock (ms_events);
        wait_for_events_raising_complete (lock);
        auto it = std::find (m_vSubscribers.begin (), m_vSubscribers.end (), pSubscriber);
        assert (it != m_vSubscribers.end ());
        if (it != m_vSubscribers.end ())
            m_vSubscribers.erase (it);
    }

private:
    static std::mutex ms_events;
    unsigned m_rasingEvents;

protected:
    std::vector <vmsConsumesVaEvents*> m_vSubscribers;

protected:
    void wait_for_events_raising_complete (std::unique_lock <std::mutex> &lock)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!m_rasingEvents)
                return;
            lock.unlock ();
            Sleep (0);
            lock.lock ();
        }
    }

    void begin_raise_events ()
    {
        std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock (ms_events);
        m_rasingEvents++;
    }

    void end_raise_events ()
    {
        std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock (ms_events);
        assert (m_rasingEvents);
        m_rasingEvents--;
    }

protected:
    void RaiseEvent (unsigned nEvent, ...)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start (args, nEvent);

        begin_raise_events ();

        for (auto it = m_vSubscribers.begin (); it != m_vSubscribers.end (); ++it)
            (*it)->onVaEvent (this, nEvent, args);

        end_raise_events ();

        va_end (args);
    }
};

__declspec(selectany) std::mutex vmsRaisesVaEvents::ms_events;
```

I get crash in vmsRaisesVaEvents::SubscribeToVaEvents on this line:

```
std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock (ms_events);
```

Why so? The only suspecting thing is:

```
__declspec(selectany) std::mutex vmsRaisesVaEvents::ms_events;
```

Other than this, all objects must be in fine state (exists, not damaged, etc.).

Comment: Such is the burden of getting crash-dumps automatically.  You see things you don't want to know about.  The user's machine is messed up, ETW is broken.  This is beyond your control.

Comment: I must say this is a top crasher bug by the moment :(  Only for x64 btw. About 1 per 10000 of our users.

Comment: What you do mean by "get crash"?  I don't see any exception details or error codes in your post.  Normally a crash report starts with the indication of a bad memory access or more exotic thing that caused the unhandled SEH.

Comment: Process Architecture: x64
Exception Code: 0xC0000005
Exception Information: The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
OS Version: 6.1.7600

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEE9CCEE50 (msvcr120.dll) in dump.dmp: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.